# Session not persistent while using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm using `AJAX post` request to set `session` values with `Laravel 5.4` :

```js
$.post('http://www.example.com/api/setSessionValue', {
  "data": data
})
```

```php
public function setSessionValue() {
    $data = Input::get('data');
    // ...
    Session::put('value', $data);
}
```

But my value is never set in `session`, or set but non persistent.

I can't understand why since I'm already using session in the same way in my Laravel project, and it's working fine.

**EDIT:**

I forgot to specify that in in development mode (`artisan serve`), it's working absolutely fine.

Comment: Have you debugged this at all, to determine if the value is what you expect it to be in JS, and is sent correctly, and received properly on the server?

Comment: Yes I did, the post request is working fine. Also `$data` is a PHP array correctly valued by the data I want to receive.

Comment: try using `Request` like `$request->data`

Comment: @JoshKisb I did it, still not working.

Comment: Does the fact that you are using an absolute URL here mean that this is a cross-domain request? In that case, please go read up on what you need to do to get cookies send with it.

Comment: @CBroe Yes it is. By reading your post I found some informations about configurations to set in `config/session.php`, but nothing concrete. Do you have other information to tell me about what you said ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342140/cross-domain-cookies

Answer (score 2):

From the looks of it, you most likely are storing your API routes in the the **routes/api.php** file. That file uses a separate group of middleware that does not maintain state (does not use the StartSession middleware), as APIs by design, should be stateless.

If you must, try moving your API routes in to the **routes/web.php** file to see if it works. If it does, you can add the following middleware to the API middleware group in **app/http/kernel.php**

```
 \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
```